# Unable to find property file

Tags: java, spring

I have a number of Java property files which used to be included in the standard `resources` directory and the following property holder of Spring works fine.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/project/myproperty.properties/>
```

For some reason, I need to move them to another location so that they are not included as part of the JAR. The deployment script will handle them and copy them to a specific location called `config`.

I added the new location to the `classpath` argument of my java command, however, the above statement always fails, complaining no property file is found. My command is a follows

```
java -classpath "C:\Deployment\config" ............
```

And the property file does exist under:

```
C:\Deployment\config\project\myproperty.properties
```

Can someone let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: Try `classpath:*/myprpoerty.properties`.

Comment: By the way it should be spelt as *myproperty*.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${my.config.location}\project\myproperty.properties"/>
```

And to add the property in the environment properties:

```
java -Dmy.config.location="C:\Deployment\config" ...
```

Hope this helps.